# extjs remove duplicate value before storing it into a store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I try to remove the duplicate value before storing it into a store. I want to store the same value in the store 1 time only. But it seems the following Ext.Array.unique line does not working. Could anyone please help me to correct this. 
Thank you

```
var input1store = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: [{name: 'name'}],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'xml.result'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: false,
    sorters: [{property: 'name', direction: 'asc'}],
    listeners:{
        load: function(rec){
            uniqueArray = Ext.Array.unique(rec.getRange());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of Ext is this? 3.4?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? You load the store and then assign something to local variable. What should be the outcome?

Comment: I fetched the data from www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1. But this data has duplicate value. I want to remove the duplicate value. Then put it into input1store.  That is all I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`filterBy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.4/#!/api/Ext.util.AbstractMixedCollection-method-filterBy) method to filter out records that you don't want to appear in the store after loading.

Note that the store will keep a copy of the filtered out records, that it would restore if `clearFilter` is called (that could be by you or the component using the store). If you want to get rid definitively of these records, you'll have to delete that copy.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name'],

    // example data
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        data: [{name: 'Foo'},{name:'Bar'},{a:'Baz'},{a:'Foo'},{a:'Bar'}],
    },

    listeners: {
        load: function(store) {
            // using a map of already used names
            const hits = {}
            store.filterBy(record => {
                const name = record.get('name')
                if (hits[name]) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    hits[name] = true
                    return true
                }
            })

            // delete the filtered out records
            delete store.snapshot
        },
    },
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a great solution, it will work, but will be problematic when filtering again on other attributes, and will affect some other operations on the store. Maybe it would be better to load the data using Ajax.request, filtering, and loading only the unique values to the store.

Comment: That's what I told myself, that's why I edited my answer. Initially I thought about doing it by overriding `loadRecords`, but I thought that would be easier to understand by the OP this way.

Comment: You should clarify your first paragraph to talk about your edited answer.  You're code makes sense, just describe it better.

Comment: @JeffDiederiks Ah ah, good old times. There was really no perfect way for placing commas in ES3. Here's how I would do it today, that's beautiful! Do _you_ find it any better?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `idProperty` value (idProperty == 'name') in your store
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty.