# Remove duplicate values in a combobox in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I get the values for a combobox from a store named Accounts. There are duplicate currencies present in the store. Is there any way/config to remove the duplicates.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name: 'currency',
    action: 'selectAction',
    padding: '0 7',
    editable: false,
    displayField: 'currency',
    value_field: 'currency',
    store: 'Accounts'
}
```

Comment: I'm on my phone and a little rusty in ext, but I think your best bet is to create a new instance of the store, and either remove the duplicate currencies in a each loop, or write a filterBy function, then use that store in your combo.  If it needs to be reloaded/filtered every time the object shows our is created, do it all in the init function or catch the appropriate event.

Comment: Can you write an event for the store Accounts and check itself in the store. loop there in the event and remove the duplicates.

Comment: Check the below url.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947624/extjs-remove-duplicate-value-before-storing-it-into-a-store

Comment: why are there duplicate entries in there? does it serve any purpose? Is the store remote?